# Save a DiGraph and the read it

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to:

- create a DiGraph
- read a Digraph from a file
- Operate with a Digraph.

Code to create DiGraph()

```py
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
g.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2, 1),
                  (1, 3),(3, 1),
                  (3, 4), (4, 3),
                  (4, 5), (5, 4),
                  (4, 6), (6, 4),
                  (6, 7), (7, 6),
                  (7, 8), (8, 7),
                  (1, 9), (2, 9),(3, 9), (4, 9),(5, 9), (6, 9),
                          (7, 9), (8, 9),
                      ])

print("g Is directed:", nx.is_directed(g))
nx.write_multiline_adjlist(g, 'test.adjlist')
```

So far this is a directed Graph.

Then I read the graph and when I print is it is directed or not the result is `False`

```py
G = nx.read_adjlist('test.adjlist')
print("G Is directed:", nx.is_directed(G))
```

I have also tried to save it as a `.yaml` but the function to read the `.yaml` uses a deprecated version of yaml and therefore generates a warning

```py
print("g Is directed:", nx.is_directed(g))
nx.write_yaml(g, 'test_2.yaml')

G = nx.read_yaml('test_2.yaml')
print("G Is directed:", nx.is_directed(G))
```

This makes a Directed graph but I get the Error:

```py
YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  G = yaml.load(path)
```

Comment: You could use [`create_using=nx.DiGraph()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.multiline_adjlist.read_multiline_adjlist.html#read-multiline-adjlist) to overrule the default, and get a directed graph instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nelewout commented:

```
create_using=nx.DiGraph()
```

to overrule the default, and get a directed graph instead